# Questions about faster rcnn

Tags: tensorflow, detection, object-detection

I am reading the [code](https://github.com/CharlesShang/TFFRCNN) for faster rcnn. And I have several question:

(1) I don't know whats the meaning of cfg.TRAIN.OHEM.

(2) what's the different between rpn_bbox_inside_weights and rpn_bbox_outside_weights.

(3) In the TFFRCNN-master/lib/networs/network.py (build_loss), when calculate the loss, some code appears like:

```
tf.gather(rpn_cls_score, rpn_keep)
tf.gather(rpn_label, rpn_keep)
```

why rpn_keep should be gathered?

(4) It calculate loss as

```
loss = cross_entropy + loss_box + rpn_cross_entropy + rpn_loss_box
```

which means it combine the classification and rpn step. But in the paper, the author means the rpn was firstly trained, and the classification was secondly trained. Is my understanding wrong?

(5) In the RPN net, it will generate m*n*9 anchors. But I can not find the relative code.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer two of my own questions.

(4) The original paper provide three method to train the network. In one of the method, the RPN and classification was combined to train.

Of course, in another method, the Faster rcnn can train the RPN firstly and classification secondy.

(5) As for how to generate m*n*9 anchors, in the code lib/networsk/VGGnet_train, line 51, the generated m*n*36 based the feature map was the 9 anchors.

As for the question (1)(2)(3), I can not find the answer. If one know the answer, please tell me.

Best, 
Qiang